# Cakephp 3, fetch details from a secondary table to send email

Tags: mysql, email, cakephp

I need some help with the CakePHP mailing feature.

I have a Users table, here I collect full name, email and role.
There's another table called Teams which has the team name, active status and manager id(this is a foreign key to Users) only the users with role 'Manager' can be selected here.
Finally, I have a table called employees, here I collect basic data and the team id where this new employee belongs.

Now, what I want to do is to send an email to the manager of the team right after the new employee is created. How can I access the manager's email from there?

Is there a way to do this as an afterSave method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.

I just added this after the new record is saved.

```
if ($this->Entity->save($entity)) {
$id = $entity->id;
$data = $this->Entity->get($id, [
'contain' => ['Other Tables']]);

$this->getMailer('Entity')->send('mail_function',[$data]);
```